# Square-integrable martingale that converges almost surely but not in $L^2$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I am looking for an example of a square-integrable martingale that converges almost surely but not in $L^2$ ? Your help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\{\xi_n,n\ge 1\}$ be the sequence of independent random variables with distribution
\begin{equation*}
 \mathsf{P}(\xi_n=\pm n)=\frac{1}{2n^2}, \quad \mathsf{P}(\xi_n=0)=1-\frac{1}{n^2}, \quad n\ge 1, \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
then
\begin{gather*}
   \mathsf{E}[\xi_n]=0, \quad \mathsf{E}[\xi_n^2]=1, \quad n\ge1, \tag{2}\\
 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathsf{P}(\xi_n\neq 0)<\infty    \quad\text{ and }\quad \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\xi_n \quad \text{converge a.s.} 
\end{gather*}
Now denote
\begin{equation*}
 X_n=\sum_{j=1}^n \xi_j, \quad n\ge 1.
\end{equation*}
From (2), $\{X_n,n\ge 1\}$ is a square integrable martingale. Also from (2),
\begin{equation*}
 \mathsf{E}[X_n^2]=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\mathsf{E}[\xi_j^2]=n\to\infty, \quad \text{as }n\to\infty, 
\end{equation*}
Hence $X_n$ does not converge in $L^2$.